What's a concept that encompasses a customer's acceptance or rejection of terms?
I'm having a real quandary regarding how to name a class [in the context of a SW application] which models the decision of a customer relative to legal terms & also specific actions (such as a newsletter subscription). I would like to choose a name which is as legally correct as possible (not easy for me since I'm a software developer, not a lawyer).
Say a customer (very typical situation) is given a choice to: subscribe to a newsletter, his/her data being used for specific purposes, receiving emails/SMS messages with specific types of info, etc.
The customer's decision may be a consent or a rejection.
Is there a legal term which means the customer's decision regarding consent, regardless of whether that decision is affirmative or negative?
Afaik, talking about a customer's consent implies the customer accepted or consented.
Some possibilities:

ConsentDecision -- not really because name implies agreement?
?


Have you tried reading the language of company privacy policies, which often make this kind of distinction? Credit card agreements are another place that this kind of distinction is used and you can look at the way that those are worded. So do class action lawsuit notices. Often these are worded in a way that avoids the need to have a legal term for these classes and instead it ends up in operative language.

Also, why don't you use just a Boolean? (Agreement_to_Privacy_Terms_given == FALSE) seems pretty straightforward to someone reading the code.

The customer's decision is a complex entity which includes the date of the decision and other pieces of info. The nature of the decision is indeed a boolean, but is only one property of the class.

Could be multiple variables. Like Date of presenting, version of the agreement presented, and the boolean of if they clicked Agree. But why do you need a legal term of art if it is just a list of those things in the documentation? You could just name it "Pinniped-with-Waterball" and legally there is no distinction! From a programmer standpoint, I would name it "Presented_ToS", containing "Date" "Version" and "Agreement_given"

Tbh, of course I don't need a legal term, but I would not like to use a term that's at odds with legal terminology.
According to ChatGPT the term "consent decision" can be interpreted in a broad enough way to encompass both given and declined consent. But a narrower reading of "consent decision" would be a decision that produces a consent.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I think most lawyers from common-law jurisdictions would describe this as a "response," "decision," or "election."
